# JBoss class loader order - another try to understand it

Tags: java, jboss5.x, classloader

when I deploy an application on JBoess 5.1 Jboss takes 3rd party jars from 3 different optional places that I am aware of: 
1. my-app/WEB-INF/lib 
2. [JBoss root]/lib 
3. [JBoss root]/server/all/lib

my options to configure jboss-web and hence modify JBoss' class loading that I am aware of are as following: 
**option1:**

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading> 
      <loader-repository>com.example:archive=unique-archive-name</loader-repository> 
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

**option 2:**

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
      <loader-repository>
         com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
         <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
      </loader-repository>
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

**option 3:**

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="true">
      <loader-repository>
         com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
         <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
      </loader-repository>
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

while trying those options I got different deployment exception when trying the different options. 
*My question:* what is the order of the 3 jar folders that I mentioned above in each one of those options.
those links of JBoss didn't help me to understand the different behavior: 
[link1](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/classloadingconfiguration) 
[link2](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jbossclassloadingusecases)

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links:

[Solving JBoss 5 classloading issues](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-configuration/solving-jboss-5-classloading-issues)

[useJBossWebClassLoader in JBoss5](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/useJBossWebClassLoaderinJBoss5)

JBoss 5 adds the concepts of custom meta data files, one of which is `jboss-classloading.xml` which let you define exactly how the war classloader is constructed.